# Can i directly use TemplatedItems of ListView in Xamarin.Forms to update properties?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

Because of some special reason i can not use [Xamarin.Forms Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/), I must directly update the properties of view which created by ItemTemplate in ListView.

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="TestListView.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="TestListView" />
        <Button
            Clicked="Button_Clicked"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="Change last appearing text"
            VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestListView {
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage {
        private int lastApprearingItemIndex = -1;
        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
            TestListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
                return (new ViewCell() {
                    View = new Label()
                });
            });
            TestListView.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).ToArray();
            TestListView.ItemAppearing += TestListView_ItemAppearing;
        }
        private void TestListView_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e) {
            lastApprearingItemIndex = e.ItemIndex;
            ((Label)(((ViewCell)(TestListView.TemplatedItems[e.ItemIndex])).View)).Text = "test text for id " + (int)(e.Item);
        }
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
            ((Label)(((ViewCell)(TestListView.TemplatedItems[lastApprearingItemIndex])).View)).Text = "(changed)test text for id " + lastApprearingItemIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

This test runs well in android
[image]

[image]

But in UWP it shows nothing

[image]

It runs well also in WPF.

So i have two questions:

1,Why doesn't it work in UWP?

2,Will ListView reuse the view of item like [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter) in android?

Comment: As Far as i know, you would have to use ObservableCollection, so it can notify the UI. I think the issue here is not that it doesnt update, but it just doesnt update the UI. Have a look at the values of ItemsSource after u make a change.

Comment: You can't directly modify the UI, you need to use bindings to do this

Answer (score 0):

> 1,Why doesn't it work in UWP?

Because you used `ViewCell` for your listview, and you do not binding any value to it.

If you insist not to use data-binding, you can change the background code like following format.

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
       
        ObservableCollection<string> employees;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
            employees = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                employees.Add("test text for id " + i);
            }


            TestListView.ItemsSource = employees;
       
        }
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
           
            base.OnAppearing();
           
        }
      
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //set the id that you want to change
            employees[1] = "test111";
         
        }
    }
```

Here is running gif.
[image]

> 2,Will ListView reuse the view of item like ListAdapter in android?

In the xamarin forms, there are no `ListAdapter`, So I strongly recommand you to use data-binding, code will be more elegant and easy. Here is an helpful article about it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding